# How to indent HTML properly in Vim

Tags: vim

I have this HTML code:

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <div
            class="demo"
            @click="attachRed = !attachRed"
            :class="{red: attachRed, blue: !attachRed}"
    >
    </div>
    <div
            class="demo">
    </div>
    <div
            class="demo">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  attachRed: false,
  },
  computed: {
    divClasses: function() {
    return {
      red: this.attachRed,
      blue: !this.attachRed,
    }
    }
  }
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I indent the `return` in the computed section properly to look like this in Vim?

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <div
            class="demo"
            @click="attachRed = !attachRed"
            :class="{red: attachRed, blue: !attachRed}"
    >
    </div>
    <div
            class="demo">
    </div>
    <div
            class="demo">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    attachRed: false,
  },
    computed: {
      divClasses: function() {
        return {
          red: this.attachRed,
          blue: !this.attachRed,
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change in my Vim or WebStorm settings so that when I select everything in visual mode and press <kbd>=</kbd> it indents properly?

Comment: You want it to nest one level deeper? Using the default Vim HTML tidy it worked for me. Do you have [`tidy`](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) installed on your machine? It is very configurable and you can add a command into your `$VIMRC` to trigger those custom settings using something like `vmap ,x :!tidy -q -i --show-errors 0<CR>`.

Comment: If you're not getting the output you want it _might_ be because the HMTL isn't valid. That can throw off tidy-type code.